# How to save a FANN to string?

Tags: python, c++, c, fann

I want to use FANN by saving the configuration into a database, then load it during runs. All of the functions seem to be saving/loading networks into config files. But my application can't have temporary files.

How can I save a training into a string / load a network from a string? I am using the Python bindings, but a C/C++ answer is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the IO code in, https://github.com/libfann/fann/blob/master/src/fann_io.c you can very easily create your own create_from_string function using how it reads the file as a template.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try [fann_save](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_io-h.html#fann_save) ?

### train.c

```
fann_save( ann, "./nets/trained.net" );
```

It allows to save the network and then [load it again](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_io-h.html#fann_create_from_file) in another program:

### simulate.c

```
ann = fann_create_from_file("./nets/trained.net");
```